# SK Physics Body is not colliding with Edge Physics Body

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm new to Sprite Kit and I'm trying to set up a simple game where a dropped object stays within the confines of the screen. When I drop the object, though, it does not collide with the edges of the screen like it should, it simply falls through.

I set up my scene and the edge loop around it.

```
// Create and configure the scene.
SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
scene.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:scene.frame];
scene.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -9.8);
```

And this is where I draw out my physics body for the sprite that drops wherever I touch.

```
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"SObstacle.png"];

    sprite.position = location;

    CGFloat offsetX = sprite.frame.size.width * sprite.anchorPoint.x;
    CGFloat offsetY = sprite.frame.size.height * sprite.anchorPoint.y;

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 50 - offsetX, 58 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 58 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 32 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 24 - offsetX, 32 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 24 - offsetX, -2 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 80 - offsetX, -2 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 80 - offsetX, 24 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 50 - offsetX, 24 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 50 - offsetX, 56 - offsetY);

    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

    sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];

    [self addChild:sprite];
```

I have tried this with an SKSpriteNode that was just a square (I only used coordinates and not an image) and it worked perfectly. It may just be a rookie mistake, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path outline defines a [concave shape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_and_concave_polygons) but polygon shaped bodies [must use convex shapes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithPolygonFromPath%3a).

You can either change the path to be convex or you will have to split it up into multiple bodies connected with joints in order to form a larger concave shape made out of individual convex bodies.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for clearing that up. Is there any sort of tutorial you could point me to so that I can understand creating a larger shape with individual shapes and joints? I'm assuming I would use bodyWithBodies?

Comment: right, bodyWithBodies but keep in mind this is only for ios 7.1